# Как в SimpleCursorAdapter изменить данные?

Tags: java, sqlite, cursor

Есть вот такой код:

```
CursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
    cursor,
    new String[]{"NAME", "DESC"},
    new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2},
    0);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Но мне нужно чтобы код был примерно таков:

```
CursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, 
    cursor, 
    new String[]{getString(R.string.name) + "NAME",
        getString(R.string.description) + "DESC"},
    new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2},
    0);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Те берется значение из values, соединяется вместе со значение из бд (курсора) и в списке уже был вид:
`Строка из ресурсов + имя из бд`
`Строка из ресурсов + описание из бд`

ps 2 код не работает тк курсор думает то что это имя колонки (строка из ресурсов + "NAME")

Comment: Похоже придется делать свой адаптер ...